# Rewrite with region in URL

Tags: regex, apache

I'm trying to rewrite a url containing a region and language code. It's hard to explain, so I'll just demonstrate

I'd like `https://www.example.com/en-us/get-started` to actually request `https://www.example.com/get-started?region=en-us`

I also want `https://www.example.com/get-started` to work as well. I'm using another regex to rewrite requests. This is what I'm using at the moment to do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

I've tried other regex's to include the region code, but it doesn't like to play nice with the above regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with the regex, I found that this works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/(.*)$ /$2?region=$1 [L,QSA]
```